# What does the "sh" function do in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

What does this function do?

```
def getVersion(){
    def commitHash = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'
    return commitHash
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is executing the `git rev-parse --short HEAD` shell command and returning the commit hash that is associated with the current `HEAD`.

Comment: FYI... `rev-parse` documentation is available at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse.